# Window function: Summing for only distinct value in the other column

Tags: sql, window-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

*Note: This questions seems to have gotten decent views so I thought it's better I update this question for clarity. Most changes are cosmetic, but the only major change is that I added month column to the weights_table. Weights tables are monthly tables so technically it doesn't matter, but I guess having month column in both tables would make table relationship more obvious and logical*

**Problem**

I have this query that uses two tables [**person_table**] and [**weights_table**].

```
select 
a.month,
a.movie,
count(a.person_id) as raw,
sum(b.weight) as weighted,
sum(b.weight)/sum(sum(b.weight)) over () as share -- I need to change this calculation 
from (select distinct month, 
                      movie, 
                      person_id 
      from person_table) a 
join weights_table b on a.month=b.month and a.person_id=b.person_id
group by a.month, a.movie;
```

What I want is to change that last calculation such that the denominator `sum(sum(b.weight)) over ()` is calculated as sum of the sum of weights for (distinct person_ids per month) instead of sum of the sum of weights for (distinct person_ids per movie per month). Is there an easier way to accommodate that without adding another subquery?

**Sample of person_table**

```
+-------+-------+-----------+
| month | movie | person_id |
+-------+-------+-----------+
|     1 |    a  |         1 |
|     1 |    b  |         1 |
|     1 |    b  |         2 |
|     1 |    a  |         2 |
|     1 |    c  |         3 |
|     1 |    d  |         4 |
|     1 |    a  |         2 |
|     1 |    c  |         3 |
|     1 |    a  |         6 |
+-------+-------+-----------+
```

**Sample of weights_table**

```
+-------+-----------+--------+
| month | person_id | weight |
+-------+-----------+--------+
|     1 |         1 |     12 |
|     1 |         2 |     34 |
|     1 |         3 |     65 |
|     1 |         4 |     76 |
|     1 |         7 |     96 |
+-------+-----------+--------+
```

[**DDL Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7d9a7e9b769c1dfa7146f058248039b)

**Expected result**

```
+-------+-------+-----+----------+-------+
| month | movie | raw | weighted | share |
+-------+-------+-----+----------+-------+
|     1 | a     |   2 |       46 |  0.25 | --(12+34)/(12+34+65+76)=0.25
|     1 | b     |   2 |       46 |  0.25 |
|     1 | c     |   1 |       64 |  0.35 |
|     1 | d     |   1 |       76 |  0.41 |
+-------+-------+-----+----------+-------+
```

**Metric definitions:**

**Raw**: Count of all distinct person_ids per month per movie)

**Weighted**: Sum of weights of distinct person_ids per month per movie).

**Share**: Ratio of **Weighted** to (Sum of weights of distinct person_ids per month matched with the persons_table)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- as would definitions of the metrics you want to calculate.

Comment: Let me add them in

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this.  You want your raw and weighted to only count a person once if they saw the same movie more than once in a month?  However, you want all of them for the share.  Is that right?

Comment: @MikeWalton For the raw and weighted, that's correct but if the same person watches another movie, it counts as 2. But for the denominator of the share, it's doesn't matter what movie they watch. I want to sum the corresponding weights of only distinct person_id for the month.

Comment: Would you please show us the result that you would expect for that sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, with only one months data in a the table, and decomposing the subselect to CTE's to see if I can see a pattern. I don't see any.. and thus it seems like a how you like your SQL thing (to me)

```
with person_table as (
    select column1 as month, column2 as movie, column3 as person_id, column4 as unique_visit_id
    from values (1, 'a', 1, 1),  
        (1, 'b', 1, 2),
        (1, 'b', 2, 3),
        (1, 'a', 2, 4),
        (1, 'c', 3, 5),
        (1, 'd', 4, 6),
        (1, 'a', 2, 7),
        (1, 'c', 3, 8),
        (1, 'a', 6, 9)
), weight_table as (
    select column1 as person_id, column2 as weight
    from values (1, 12), (2, 34), (3, 65), (4, 76), (999,999)
), dis_month_people as (
    select distinct month, person_id 
    from person_table
), month_share as (
    select month, sum(weight) as total_weight
    from dis_month_people dp
    join weight_table w on dp.person_id = w.person_id
    group by 1
), dis_month_movie_people as (
    select distinct month, movie, person_id
    from person_table
)
select t.* --, weighted, total_weight
    ,t.weighted/m.total_weight as share
from (
  select 
    a.month,
    a.movie,
    count(a.person_id) as raw,
    sum(b.weight) as weighted
  from dis_month_movie_people a 
  join weight_table b on a.person_id = b.person_id
  group by 1,2
) AS t
join month_share m on t.month = m.month 
order by 1,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
select a.month,
    a.movie,
    count(a.person_id) as raw,
    sum(b.weight) as weighted,
    100*weighted/c.ttl_weight as share
from (select distinct month, movie, person_id from person_table) a 
inner join weights_table b on a.person_id=b.person_id
cross join (select sum(weight) as ttl_weight from weights_table w
            where exists (select 1 
                          from person_table p 
                          where w.person_id=p.person_id)
           ) c
group by a.month, a.movie, c.ttl_weight
;
```

Comment: if you add a user row to weight, that is not present in the monthly data this sums that row.